# Documenting two S3 methods in the same file with Roxygen

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I have two methods for an S3 generic (defined in another package) that are closely related and so I wanted to document them in the same `Rd` file. However, when I document their arguments separately, I get a warning from `R CMD check` about "Duplicated \argument entries in documentation object"

```
##' Create a ggplot of a Kaplan-Meier Survival curve(s)
##'
##' @param data  A \code{survfit} object returned from \code{\link{survfit}}
##' @param \dots Unused
##' @return A ggplot2 object
autoplot.survfit <- function(data, ...) {
    NULL
}

##' @rdname autoplot.survfit
##' @param data A \code{\link{survfit.fortify}} object returned from \code{\link{fortify.survfit}}
autoplot.survfit.fortify <- function(data, ...) {
    NULL
}
```

The first argument must be `data` because that is what the generic defines. However, the documentation for it is different for the different methods, if only because it must be of a different class.  I could have two separate documentation files for this, but they are closely coupled so I would like to keep them together. I could list all possible classes of `data` in the first invocation and not have anything in the subsequent ones, but that means I'm documenting the second function with the first rather than keeping it all together as is the point of Roxygen.

Is it possible to get roxygen to create a legal (not duplicating the argument) from multiple methods? If not, what is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Copy and paste the same text?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen But then both texts would have to describe both cases, which breaks the compartmentalization of the documentation.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Did you ever find a nice way to do this?

Comment: @Dason No, I have not. I have some ideas for how `roxygen2` could be modified to handle this gracefully as part of the processing, but I have not worked on implementing them or even seeing if they are feasible.

Comment: I have some ideas of how it might be possible but I haven't attempted to try them out.  I was just asking to see if there is a nicer way that you've found yet.  If my attempts work I'll post an answer.

Comment: If these are going in the same Rd file, then shouldn't there be only one `@param` that covers both methods? If you think about the Rd file if you write it by hand, you would write `\item{data}{an object of class \code{"survfit"} or \code{"survfit.fortify} as returned by \code{\link{survfit}} or \code{\link{fortify.survfit}}`. It doesn't make sense to document this twice, does it, and it is not allowed by the Rd parser. I would just write one `@param data blah blah` (as per my Rd markup above) in the block for the first S3 method documented and leave it at that.

Comment: @GavinSimpson That works and would give a valid Rd file, but it violates the principle of keeping the documentation with the code since part of the documentation for the second function is with the code for the first function.

Comment: I can't see how that could be avoided given the general way roxygen2 works and the requirements of Rd files?

Comment: It looks like you may have something nice to add to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2953641/903061) on using ggplot with the survival package.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea behind S3 generic methods is that it should not be necessary to have different descriptions for the same argument.

It is clear from the usage section which classes are accepted (for the argument on which the dispatch takes place), if you produce S3 method documentation with `##' @method` and `##' @S3method`. For the other arguments, I'd say that needing different descriptions is probably an indicator that different argument names should be used.

So from:

```
##' Create a ggplot of a Kaplan-Meier Survival curve(s)
##'
##' @param data  the object to be plotted
##' @param \dots Unused
##' @method autoplot survfit
##' @S3method autoplot survfit
##' @return A ggplot2 object
autoplot.survfit <- function(data, ...) {
    NULL
}

##' @rdname autoplot.survfit
##' @method autoplot survfit.fortify
##' @S3method autoplot survfit.fortify
autoplot.survfit.fortify <- function(data, ...) {
    NULL
}
```

I get with `roxygen2`

```
Create a ggplot of a Kaplan-Meier Survival curve(s)

Description:

Create a ggplot of a Kaplan-Meier Survival curve(s)

Usage:

     ## S3 method for class 'survfit'
      autoplot(data, ...)

     ## S3 method for class 'survfit.fortify'
      autoplot(data, ...)

Arguments:

    data: the object to be plotted

     ...: Unused

Value:

     A ggplot2 object
```

Answer (score 0):

If the argument names need different descriptions, it is acceptable to document the separate methods in separate files. This is not my opinion, it is how they do it in the R source code.  And if they do it, it must be right. Look at the documentation pages for the package "stats". Note there are separate files for predict.arima, predict.gls, and so forth.

In the R source, there are several different files for print methods. Observe:

```
$ find . -name "print*.Rd"
./base/man/print.Rd
./base/man/print.dataframe.Rd
./base/man/print.default.Rd
./stats/man/print.power.htest.Rd
./stats/man/printCoefmat.Rd
./stats/man/print.ts.Rd
./tools/man/print.via.format.Rd`
```

I do not agree with the previous poster who suggested that you should re-name the arguments if they need different descriptions. That under-cuts the object-oriented idea of polymorphism, which encourages us to not proliferate different names unless necessary.